# php checking if form was submitting with null field

Tags: php, submit, isset

As the title says, I'm trying to figure out how to check if there were any null entries in a form after the submit button has been clicked.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($selected == ''|| $text == '' || $email == ''))
{
  // *do things*
}
else{
  //*more things*
}
```

is this incorrect?

Comment: $selected, $email, $text are a forms input?

Comment: Probably need to post some more code..

Comment: sorry for not answering sooner, yes they are input that have already been retrieved, but this code has done nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would reference them in the same way that you handled the submit button.

That is: `$_POST['input_name']`

From there check it using the appropriate function: `isset()`, `empty()`, `is_null()` (although form variables rarely come across as `null`)

I'd also encourage you to read up on [PHP external variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Comment: But I've already set them to those variables earlier in the code.

Comment: Then jump to the second part of my answer.

Comment: Watch out for empty(). Returns true also for values such as "0"; might not be what you want. Since $_POST variables get to you as strings, I'd use strlen() instead. Just my 2cc.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to loop over the $_POST variables. Exclude those in which you're not interested in, and make something like:

```
$allIsOk = true;
foreach ($_POST as $index => $value) {
  if (strlen($value)<1) {
    $allIsOk = false;      
  }
}
```

...and then you make your choice on $allIsOk.

This approach is for two reasons:

1. With suggestion above, you need to combine checks, since empty()
   will return true for 0 or even "0" and might cause headbanging
   problems.
2. With this approach you can add parameters, without
   making a huge if statement

Of course, this is just the idea. It's always wise to check documentation. Also, you could substitute the foreach cycle with an array_walk invocation to make things fancier (esp. from PHP 5.3 onwards). ;-)

Good luck!

PS Also, to find out whether your script has been invoked by a POST action, instead of taking into account the submit element, I suggest you to use the $_SERVER global. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php Just check for the 'REQUEST_METHOD' parameter.

So, you might have:

```
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {

  // It's ok for these to be null - or empty
  $exclude = array('submit', 'other_param');
  $allIsOk = true;
  foreach ($_POST as $index => $value) {
    if (!in_array($index, $exclude) && strlen($value)<1) {
      $allIsOk = false;      
    }
  }
}

if ($allIsOk) {
  // Do Something
} else {
  // Do Something Else
}
```